# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/Mongo;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spring-boot, mongobee

While trying to run Spring-boot application (v2.1.0) getting below error:

> Description:
>   
>   An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.(Lcom/mongodb/Mongo;Ljava/lang/String;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate, is available from the following locations:
>   
>       file:/C:/Users/npatil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.class
>   
>   It was loaded from the following location:
>   
>       file:/C:/Users/npatil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
>   
>   Action:
>   
>   Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate

Below is a snnipet from my pom:

```
<dependencies>
.
.
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mongobee</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
    <version>0.13</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
.
.
</dependencies>
```

Version of some of the jars that could help are:
`spring-data-mongodb` : `2.1.2.RELEASE`
`spring-web` : `5.1.2.RELEASE`
`mongo-java-driver` : `3.8.2.RELEASE`

Deleted `.m2` and did `mvn clean install`, but even that did not resolve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with  `Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE`

Comment: din't work :(
Any specific reason for making it to `2.0.0`?

Comment: There was nothing to do with the boot version. There is a call to constructor `new MongoTemplate(MongoClient mongoClient, String databaseName)`, when I ctrl-click on it, it goes to `Object` class. This was perhaps some issues with loading of `jars`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jar is corrupted or missing, 
check all spring related jar are 4.x or higher version
if that doent work then: 
  Mongobee depends on Spring 4.x jars which may conflicts with Spring boot 2.x

try the below way

```
  @Bean
  public Mongobee mongobee(){
    Mongobee mongobee = new Mongobee("mongodb://localhost:27017/seed");
    mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage(InitialData.class.getPackageName());
            mongobee.setMongoTemplate(template);

    return mongobee;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change [Mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee) by [Mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock) if you use Springboot 2. The syntax is almost the same because the Mongock project is the continuation of the Mongobee project.

**Springboot:**

```
@Bean
public SpringBootMongock mongock(ApplicationContext springContext, MongoClient mongoClient) {
  return (SpringBootMongock) new SpringBootMongockBuilder(mongoClient, "yourDbName", "com.package.to.be.scanned.for.changesets")
      .setApplicationContext(springContext) 
      .setLockQuickConfig()
      .build();
}
```

**Spring:**

```
@Bean
public SpringMongock mongock() {
  MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("yourDbName", yourMongoClientBuilder));
  return new SpringMongockBuilder(mongoclient, "yourDbName", "com.package.to.be.scanned.for.changesets")
      .setLockQuickConfig()
      .build();
}
```